# orderby date angularjs ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, date, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-orderby

i'm trying to orderby 'date' together with ng-repeat but my date format is  "date": "Sun, 01 Sep 2016 08:47:53 -0400". i tried using momentjs but i'm getting a wrong list.

pls, how do i orderby date

http://codepen.io/netwrkx/pen/WGbwgY?editors=101

```
<tr ng-repeat="expense in expenses | orderBy:'date'">
    <td>{{expense.name}}</td>
    <td>{{expense.amount}}</td>
    <td>{{expense.date |  amTimeAgo}} </td> 
</tr>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<tr ng-repeat="expense in expenses | orderBy:compareDateFunc">
```

and

```
$scope.compareDateFunc = function(dt) {
  return new Date(dt.date);
}
```

Comment: it worked!!!  but how do i ascend or descend the ng-repeat "-compareDateFunc" doesnt seem to work

Comment: `return - new Date(dt.date);` changes the order

Answer (score 2):

You can create your custom filter `dateOrder` which gives input to in built filter.

JS :

```
.filter('dateOrder',function(){

   return function(data){ 
     angular.forEach(data,function(val,key){
       val.dateTimestamp = new Date(val.date).getTime()

     });
     return data; 

   }  
});
```

Define your html as :

```
<tr ng-repeat="expense in expenses | dateOrder |orderBy :'dateTimestamp'">
```

Here is the working [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/QKwEwR?editors=1010#anon-login)

Comment: worked, thanks. should i be concern about the performance aspect of this code. imagine loading 100 json object

Comment: You can prepared timestamp data in `date` in controller.Then filter according  `date.  <tr ng-repeat="expense in expenses | orderBy :'data'">`